# Select Statement with RegEx Replace - DB2 9.7

Tags: select, db2, db2-luw, regular-expression

In a db2 9.7 select statement's field, I need to perform a global regular expression that replaces multiple white spaces (between words) with exactly one space. The regular expression would be base on something like this:

```
\s{2,}
```

The query (without thinning out redundant white space) looks like this:

```
select
  random_degrees_of_redundant_white-space_between_words as fieldName
from tableName
```

The contents of a result looks like this:

```
I like  to   put    varying      numbers      of    whitespaces

     between

   words.
```

I've seen examples of people claiming to achieve this in DB2 9.7 via xmlquery and fn:replace, but I can't seem to accomplish this myself by looking at their examples.

Would someone be kind enough to convert my abstract example into something I can use as a model for achieving this in db2 9.7?

Please do not provide answers that achieve this via custom functions or stored procedures. I want to achieve this using an independent select statement on a default installation of DB2 9.7 (without installing any addons to db2).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the the

> replace

function like this:

```
select replace('Text   with  random      spaces', '  ', ' ') 
  from yourtable
```

The second argument shows two spaces and the third is a single blank.

**EDIT:**

For multiple blanks this sould work - natively:

```
SELECT c1, length(c1), xmlquery('fn:replace($c,"[ ]+", " ")'  PASSING c1 AS "c") 
  FROM test1
```

Comment: Sorry, that'll just compress doubled spaces to one space; it won't replace multiple consecutive spaces with a single one

Comment: For the OP, I'm afraid this is one area DB2 is rather weak: no built-in regex support, and no other built-in pattern matching (beyond the usual `LIKE` support). As you've discovered there are methods using xmlquery (and others using recursive queries) but to me they all seem horribly over-complex compared to a straight scalar function for this. There are some third party libs which provide regex support (including mine :), but you're looking for something that'll work in a "vanilla" install I'm afraid you're in for some pain.

Comment: @DaveJones : "vanilla" is ideal, but I'd still be interested in seeing what you've created.

Comment: My db2utils suite has a bunch of PCRE driven functions including [PCRE_SUB](http://db2utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/PCRE_SUB.html). I should stress this *isn't* what you're looking for: it only does single, not global replace but it wouldn't be difficult to extend for this (PRs welcome; sadly I've no time/motivation to work on db2utils these days as I don't work with DB2 anymore but I keep it alive for anyone interested).